# Setting up tomcat6 using mod_jk for Apache, page not found using https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, tomcat6, mod-jk

I have been trying to setup an Apache web server along with a Tomcat6 web server, using SSL/HTTPS. On my Apache web server the SSL is working correctly, and I can access the web pages it serves up using SSL/HTTPS, but I am having a problem accessing the web apps on the Tomcat server using SSL/HTTPS.  The new setup is on a Centos 6 machine, and I have a similar setup on a Fedora 13 machine.

I have compared all the files that I can think of between the two machines, but can not get to the web apps using HTTPS.  When I try I get a "Not Found" error.  I can access the web apps if I use just HTTP.

Can anyone point me to where my problem might be?

Thank you